# Writing crud operations for Azure COSMOS DB

Tags: java, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am trying to build a generic war for crud operations of Azure CosMos DB. The idea is to build a generic war without having any model objects, that would just receive json input having the collection ID, query params. We would build query based on query params recieved in JSON Input and would run query on documents in collection. So that if and when there are any changes to any model objects we don't need to change this war everytime.

So I have build a sample but I am not able to run the select queries . So is it possible to build such project with cosmosdb and if yes, any help on how to run sql queries , with group by, order by clauses.

I have checked on microsoft sites, found many links but there they are making model objects like AndersonFamily, wakeFamily and using them. In my case I don't want any model objects in the war, I want it to be generic so that the war is not changed on every change of model objects.

Sample code:

```
try {
        DocumentClient documentClient = AzureCosmosDBFactory.getDocumentClient();
        DocumentCollection documentCollection = AzureCosmosDBClient.getDocumentCollection();
        List documents = AzureCosmosDBFactory.getDocumentClient().queryDocuments(AzureCosmosDBClient.getDocumentCollection().getSelfLink(), "select c.data.companyid from  c", null).getQueryIterable().toList();
        if (documents.size() > 0) {
            return new ResponseEntity(documents, HttpStatus.OK);
        } else {
            return new ResponseEntity(PropertyConstants.DATA_NOT_FOUND, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
    }catch(Throwable t){
        t.printStackTrace();
        return new ResponseEntity(PropertyConstants.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR+ t.getCause() , HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
```

Now, here when I do a select * from c, then I am getting correct response. But when I do select c.data.companyid from c then I am not getting correct data.

Comment: Please share your code and tell us what are the problems you're facing. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Please find updated the code for select query

Comment: Define "correct data". Your query returns the "correct data" from what I can see. https://i.imgur.com/0jBJRFA.png . What is the output that you would expect?

Comment: Please share an example schema of your documents when asking query questions with Cosmos DB.

Comment: Could you share the exact error you are getting?

Comment: Hi, 
Thanks all for your interest in helping me out to solve the issue. Issue got solved. Actually I am new to CosMos DB . There were two records in the DB. One was inside the children node "data" other was at root level. So that is why select all was giving all data but when I was querying using where clause so as I was passing c.data.companyid in the code above so only one record was returned.